# Replicating row in pandas Python with an If statement

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I want to duplicate rows in the code below.  If bugs equals `2` I want to duplicate the row two times, or if bugs equal to `3` I want to duplicate the row *three times*, and so on. In the example below, if I duplicate B (because it's equal than 2) I want its values to drop by one. The result is as follow in `the_result_i_want`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
  'id': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  'bugs' : [  1,   2,   3],
})

the_result_i_want = pd.DataFrame(data={
  'id': ['A', 'B','B', 'C','C','C'],
  'bugs' : [1, 1,  1,   1,  1,   1],
})
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def dup(df):
    length = len(df)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','bugs'])
    for row in range(length):
        id_ = df['id'][row]
        times = df['bugs'][row]
        sub_df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[id_]*times, 'bugs':[1]*times})
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df,sub_df])
    return new_df

dup(df)
```

Comment: The `.to_list()` calls aren't necessary.

Comment: While this code-only answer may solve the problem at hand, it is better to add explanations to help future readers understand how to apply this solution to their situation.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This function gets DataFrame object like above and returns DataFrame with 'bugs' rows for each id